# Can anyone explain me about service in my simple application with service and asyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service, android-context

I have a simple application with Service and AsyncTask class. When I start the service the BackgroundTask class which extends AsyncTask runs some simulate task and show some progress.
Here in the same BackgroundTask class, I can not understand why is Service service in the class constructor, and why in MyService class in the onStartCommand method BackgroundTask constructor accepts this as an argument.

MainActivity class:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btnStartService;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnStartService = findViewById(R.id.btnStartService);
        btnStartService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
                startService(intent);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

MyService class:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service {

    private static final int TASK_COUNT = 3;
    private boolean serviceOn = false;

    public MyService() {
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        if (!serviceOn){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Service starting...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
            backgroundTask.execute(TASK_COUNT);
            serviceOn = true;
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Service has already started...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service stoped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

BackgroundTask class:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String> {


    private Service service;


    public BackgroundTask(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
        int taskCount = integers[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < taskCount;i++){
            performLongTask();
            publishProgress((int) ((i+1) / (float) taskCount * 100));
        }
        String result = taskCount + " "+service.getString(R.string.finished);

        return result;
    }

    private void performLongTask() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        String text = values[0] + "% " + service.getResources().getString(R.string.finished);
        Toast.makeText(service, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(service, s+" mark", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        service.stopSelf();
    }
}
```

QUESTIONS:

1. What is a meaning of "Service service" in BackgroundTask class constructor, and why this class accepts "this" as an argument in onStartCommand method from MyService class?
2. Can I instead of "Service service" in BackgroundTask class use "Context context" or some combination with "Service service" because of service needs for stopSelf method?
3. How can I manage to reference a string resource with service in BackgroundTask class
   with this code: "service.getString(R.string.finished);"?

Comment: 1) `this` refers to the class instance, since your class `MyService` IS A `Service` then you pass a `Service` instance.  2) `Service` IS A `Context`. Use `IntentService` which is used for running tasks on a separate `Thread` then finishing once completed automatically 3) Service is a subclass of `ContextWrapper` which is a subclass of `Context`. - Your questions go into the more general understanding of Java and OOP arena.

Answer (score 0):

In you use case I don't think you need "MyService" to start with. Simply use AsyncTask will do. Especially "MyService" still runs on UI thread so I don't see a point of wrapping AsyncTask with a Service.

Plus don't pass Context/Service/Activity to AsyncTask as this forms an explicit reference and may cause memory leak.